# wxWidgets - append item to bottom of listctrl

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I've been searching for a while and I haven't found the magic I thought existed.

inserting at -1 didn't work (0 is top) I've not tried inserting at `maxint` because the `long`s wx gives back are (very probably) not ordered, I conclude this because if I insert an item between two others, there's no magical way for all the `long`s given out to everything after it to increment by 1. So I've always assumed these are some unordered IDs wx can make sense of.

I don't always insert in order so keeping the last generated one wont work, how in wx do I insert something to the bottom of a listctrl?

I've tagged this with wxPython as well because if you know one you know the other.

Is my understanding of the `long`s returned correct? I've never messed with them manually. My part of the abstraction contract - don't touch the things it gives me to keep track of stuff, and in return it'll work.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for either:

1. `list.InsertStringItem(list.GetItemCount(), "...")`
2. `list.Append(["...", "..."])`

As in this example:

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.list = wx.ListCtrl(self.panel, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, "No.")
        self.list.InsertColumn(1, "Description")
        self.list.Arrange()

        for i in range(5):
            self.list.InsertStringItem(i, str(i))
            self.list.SetStringItem(i, 1, "It's the %d" % (i))

        self.list.InsertStringItem(self.list.GetItemCount(), "The END")
        self.list.Append(["And the other END", ""])

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.list, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)
        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)
        self.Show()

app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Also the insert returns position of the inserted item, so it is not helpful in this case.

Comment: I'll post a c++ answer to go along with this but yeah, I read up on IDs last night. They are not actually Ids!